# Cypress on Gitlab do not save video in default folder

Tags: video, gitlab, automated-tests, cypress

**Issue.**
I'm trying to save a video of a failed Cypress test which run via Gtilab CI/CD. However, instead of the specified folder, the video is saved to this path:
/builds/0/project-name/cypress/videos/sanity/main.spec.js.mp4
And I have no access to the path started with "/builds/0/".

**What have I done before.**

1. Add some settings in file cypress.json:

   ```
    {
    "viewportWidth": 1920,
    "viewportHeight": 1080,
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 100000,
    "chromeWebSecurity": false,
    "failOnStatusCode": false,
    "testIsolation": false,
    "video": true,
    "videosFolder": "cypress/videos",
    "videoUploadOnPasses": false,
    "screenshotsFolder": "cypress/screenshots",
    "screenshotOnRunFailure": true
    }
   ```
2. Add some settings in file .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - .npm/
stages:
  - tests
tests:
  stage: tests
  script:
    - npm ci --force
    - npx cypress run --browser chrome
    - bash $TESTS_HELPERS_PATH\test.sh --jobId=$CI_JOB_ID --spec='cypress/integration/sanity/main_spec.js'
  when: 'always'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - cypress/screenshots/**
      - cypress/videos/**
      - cypress/reports/**
```

**Expected behavior.**
Video should saved in path: cypress/videos